# Java - How to get videoid attribute using YouTube Data API

Tags: java, android, google-api, youtube-api

I'm working at android application which should retrieve information about a movie from youtube, so I decided to implement this functionality using google-api-client library.

I want to get videoid using only movie's title, but there is only one poor sample on the project's web-site which "describes" how to use library when working with youtube.

If anybody knows how to get info I'm interested in, maybe using @Key annotation for building URL, or any other way, please let me know.

Comment: Fixed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969507/how-to-retrieve-details-of-single-video-from-youtube-using-videoid-through-data/39478514#39478514

Answer (score 0):

Use this method. It returns the youtube url of the video.

```
VideoEntry.getMediaGroup().getPlayer().getUrl()
```