# Getting video title using video id in youtube api v3 (Android)

Tags: android, video, youtube

I am trying to get youtube video details using the video id in youtube api v3. Using this url :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=AIzaSyCA-EL5sT5LCQnYauNMm2Ku_PukvBcz6ms%20&part=snippet,contentDetails
```

I get the return of :

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "usageLimits",
"reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
"message": "The Android package name and signing-certificate fingerprint, null and null, do not match the app restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.",
"extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=861763996907"
}
],
"code": 403,
"message": "The Android package name and signing-certificate fingerprint, null and null, do not match the app restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions."
}
}
```

The api key is the key is the one I got after registering the app using my SHA1 code in google developer console. How to get over this error?

Answer (score 3):

you can make a service with GET method from mobile.All you need to do is to create a server key and append this key and video id with the url and get data

for example: if you are using Volley for HTTP requests then in JsonOBjectRequest url parameter should look this:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=F4HuIqwGuBU&key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY&fields=items(id,snippet(description,channelId,title,categoryId),statistics)&part=snippet,statistics"
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HFlN.png)

This is Happening just because you havent Cleared the Security restrictions from Console Key..
Try these Steps

Step 1 :-
Go to Your Project & Click on Credentials..
(https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/key/216?project=)

Step 2:-Generate API key and click on API key

Step 3:- Click on no Restriction and Enjoy ..